# Necesito ayuda con este codigo en C no logro hacer que ejecute

Tags: c

> Una peluquería en la que hay un barbero, una silla de peluquero y N
> sillas para que se sienten los clientes en espera, si es que los hay.
> Si no hay clientes presentes, el barbero se sienta en su silla de
> peluquero y se duerme.
>
> Cuando llega un cliente, éste debe despertar al barbero dormilón. Si
> llegan más clientes mientras el barbero corta el cabello de un
> cliente, se sientan (si hay sillas desocupadas) o salen de la
> peluquería (si todas las sillas están ocupadas). Programar al barbero
> y los clientes.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<pthread.h>

#define tiempo_corte_barbero 10
 
int cant_sillas=8;


int cant_clientes_por_dia;






struct barbero {
    char dormido;
    char ocupado;
};

struct clientes{
    int nombre;
    int tiempo_corte;
    struct barbero*barber;
}  ;

void * tienda(void * cliente){
    struct clientes*client;
    client = (struct clientes*)cliente;

    printf("Acaba de llegar un cliente a la tienda \n\n");
    

    while (client->tiempo_corte>0) {

    if(client->barber->dormido=='S'){
        
        printf("El barbero se encuentra dormido\n\n");
        printf("El %s %i \n", client->nombre," ha despertado al barbero \n \n");
        
        client->barber->dormido='N';
        
        printf("El cliente %s %i \n", client->nombre,"va a ser atendido \n\n");
    
            while (client->tiempo_corte>0){
                client->tiempo_corte--;
                client->barber->ocupado='S';
            printf("El barbero esta cortando el pelo al cliente %s %i \n\n", client->nombre);
                }
    }
    
    else {  
    
    if(cant_sillas>0){
    if(client->barber->ocupado=='S'){
    printf("El barbero esta ocupado, el cliente %s %i ha tomado asiento \n \n ", client->nombre);
    cant_sillas--;
}
    else{
        cant_sillas++;
            printf("El cliente %s %i \n", client->nombre,"va a ser atendido \n\n");
                while (client->tiempo_corte>0){
                client->tiempo_corte--;
                client->barber->ocupado='S';
            printf("El barbero esta cortando el pelo al cliente %s %i \n\n", client->nombre);
                }
    }
    }
    else {
    printf("No hay sillas disponibles, el cliente %s %i se ha marchado \n \n",client->nombre);
    }
}
    if(client->tiempo_corte==0){
        printf("El cliente %s %i ha temrinado de ser atendido \n\n");
        if(cant_sillas==8){
            printf("La tienda esta vacia, el barbero se ha puesto a dormir\n\n");
            client->barber->dormido='S';
            client->barber->ocupado='N';
        }
        else{
            cant_sillas++;
            client->barber->ocupado='N';
        }
    }
    
    } 
     
} 

int main(){
//  cant_clientes_por_dia=rand()%21;
//  printf("%i",cant_clientes_por_dia);
    int i;
    
    
    
    struct barbero * barb=(struct barbero*) malloc (sizeof(struct barbero));
    struct clientes ** cli=(struct clientes**)malloc(sizeof(cant_clientes_por_dia));
    
    barb->dormido='S';
    barb->ocupado='N';
    
    pthread_t thread[cant_clientes_por_dia];


    for( i=0;i<1;i++){
         
        cli[i]->nombre=i;
        cli[i]->tiempo_corte=tiempo_corte_barbero;
        cli[i]->barber=barb;
        printf("hola");
        pthread_create(&thread[i],NULL,tienda,(void*)cli[i] );
//      printf("%s %i \n\n",cli[i]->nombre  );
        
    }
    /*
    
        for(i=0;i<cant_clientes_por_dia;i++){
            pthread_join(thread[i],NULL);   
    }
    
    
    */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! recibis algun error? agregalo en la pregunta, usa el boton [edit] y ponelo ahi

Comment: Cuál es el error?